# Augmenting config.allowedContent instead of overriding default value

Tags: ckeditor

The section entitled [Advanced Content Filter guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) in the CKEditor docs talks about how to set values for `config.allowedContent`. The documentation states that you can override the default value. No mention is made of how to obtain the default value and augment it.

For example, I want to allow `script` tags in addition to the default tags supported, as enhanced by any installed plugins. If I inspect `config.allowedContent` in the browser in the area where I set CKEditor `config` properties, I see that `allowedContent` is `undefined`. That tells m the default behavior is triggered by the value `undefined`, which is unfortunate.

How can this be done? I can think of the following approaches:

1) Somehow list the value of `allowedContent` on the console after initialization is complete. Not sure how to do that. Hard-code that value, plus `script` in the `config` section of my code. This is not the way I'd like to go forward.

2) Write a little plugin that merely adds `script` to `allowedContent`. Not sure what that would look like. This is a viable way forward.

3) Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that [`editor.config.extraAllowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent) is a remedy to your problem.

Note that CKEditor secures all `<script>` tags in your contents so included JavaScript is not executed (avoiding XSS). Anyway, for debugging purposes, `allowedContent` rules are stored in `editor.filter.allowedContent` during editor's lifetime.

Comment: I set commented out config.allowedContent, so it has the default value, and set config.extraAllowedContent="script"; Unfortunately I see Chrome in inserting extra spans, which means instead of <p>blah blah</p> I get <p><span style="font-size:15px">blah blah</span></p>. I don't see editor.filter.disallowedContent, which would be useful. I put a breakpoint inside the instanceReady method and looked at editor.filter.allowedContent. There are dozens of objects in the array and I made a gist so you can see it here https://gist.github.com/mslinn/8189208 I see <p> is defined in lines 2-16.

Comment: I do want to be able to create markup like this, using my enhanced menu: <p>blah <span class="yellow">blah</span> blah</p>. Is there a way to selectively filter out Chrome-generated content but leave the content that my menu items generate?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately there's not. In this case content is a content and there's no difference between elements created because of the [Chrome's bug](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9998) and elements created by users. Also, in this case those ugly `span`s are created during runtime and ACF is applied only to input, so even if they are not allowed they will be filtered out when loading data.

Comment: I need some way to specify allowed content. You can see from the gist that the default content filters are long. How should I proceed? Is it necessary to manually write out every allowed variation of HTML for allowedContent? This feature does not seem to have been thought through, or perhaps there is more to know than what the skimpy documentation indicates.

Comment: Every allowed variation of HTML? ACF Doesn't check hierarchies so writing out your own set shouldn't actually be that difficult even for all content. That's what I did. Writing out an XML schema would be much, much more difficult for example - I think the current ACF system is brilliant.